# How do you say that you're using a certain license?

Tags: word-choice

I write both open source and closed source software, and I always struggle with how I should write the licenses for my own software and that of third-parties.

I usually write:

> My Awesome Game is licensed under an MIT License. Read the full license terms in the file LICENSE.

"...licensed under an..." doesn't feel right to me. For starters, it means that it's likely I have to repeat the word *license* since it's often in the license name.

I know that Creative Commons use the following wording: "This project is marked with a CC0 1.0 Universal license."

Is *marked with* the correct term to use for any license? For example:

> My Awesome Game is marked with an MIT License. Read the full license terms in the file LICENSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good that you have looked at what others say in the same context.

However I'd suggest the following
expression:

> "This game is *distributed* under an MIT Licence.

Answer (score 1):

You could write, "Use of my Awesome Game is subject to the conditions specified under an MIT License. *etc.*"